# user-select:'none' Not working on electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have the following simple html:

```html
<div style="height: 97%;overflow: auto;will-change:transform;" >
    <div>
        <span unselectable="on" style="user-select: none; width: 7.70313px;">1</span>
        <div style="color: rgb(217, 179, 0); margin-left: 27.7031px;">
            <pre style="user-select: all;">A</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span unselectable="on" style="user-select: none; width: 7.70313px;">2</span>
        <div style="color: rgb(217, 179, 0); margin-left: 27.7031px;">
            <pre style="user-select: all;">B</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span unselectable="on" style="user-select: none; width: 7.70313px;">3</span>
        <div style="color: rgb(217, 179, 0); margin-left: 27.7031px;">
            <pre style="user-select: all;">C</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span unselectable="on" style="user-select: none; width: 7.70313px;">4</span>
        <div style="color: rgb(217, 179, 0); margin-left: 27.7031px;">
            <pre style="user-select: all;">D</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a very simple html, I'm trying to implement a line number like element and i don't want it to be selected.

Open the above code on a browser, Ctrl + A will return the following result:

```
A
 B
 C
 D
```

while on electron:

```
A
2
B
3
C
4
D
```

‌
So you can see the line number is still be copied to the clipboard except the first line number. Any idea on what's going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to electron to 3.0 did solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something like the following:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
cursor: default;
```

Comment: @nathan1658 it's should work. I think the problem is from another side of your code.

Comment: @nathan1658 yes :)